.net8 application won't refresh
I am pushing changes to my .net8 application on Azure using Github Actions. The build and deploy stages are both completed successfully. But there are no changes to the site html of the site. It is as if the server cache needs to be invalidated.

I cleared my local browser cache, and
I have restarted the site on Azure.
I am using a basic tier with no staging environment.
I am not publishing to a slot.
I really don't know why my changes haven't taken. They are committed in my source code.

My repo is here: https://github.com/SteveScott/Exposure-Computer-ASP/tree/master
My website is https://www.camexcalc.com
Edit: I made extensive changes by removing setup.cs and merging it with program.cs to make it the modern .net v8 style. However, even though the site compiles and runs locally, and deploys successfully, the changes are not reflected on the web even after clearing browser cache and restarting the server.

Try using Kudu to verify the timestamp of your files https://camexcalc.scm.azurewebsites.com. If they match up with the build/deploy time then GH is good. You can restart the app in kudu->command prompt: wmic process where "name='w3wp.exe'" delete for windows, killall -9 dotnet for Linux app service plans.

Do you see anything suspicious in the logs (https://camexcalc.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/024f3776fda64c66ab23d8f8603804c6/log)?

@Steve Scott Is This Working locally?

@Aslesha it is not working locally. I get a page that says it can't start .net core

@azeem it says "Deployment Successful"

@ArchitectJamie the log time corresponds to the successful deployment.

@Steve Scott If you want to work locally you need to delete Startup.cs and Add Everything in Program.cs Like this.

I see @Aslesha. I was migrating from .net core 2.0 to .net 8.0. A lot probably changed! But it compiled successfully. I am surprised it deployed successfully with that type of error.

@Steve Scott The latest versions of dotnet didn't use the startup class.

I was getting the warning 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.AddControllers(IServiceCollection)' which has 'RequiresUnreferencedCodeAttribute' can break functionality when trimming application code. MVC does not currently support trimming or native AOT. https://aka.ms/aspnet/trimming
I was publishing to Windows so I did not neet Aot.
I disabled native AOT and Trimming.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <PublishAot>false</PublishAot>
    <PublishTrimmed>false</PublishTrimmed>
 ...
</Project>

Sure enough, the trimming was causing the project to break. By disabling AOT and trimming for the Windows server, the changes were reflected to the site.
